# jQuery scrolling div not behaving in Safari (but can replicate in jsFiddle on Chrome)

Tags: jquery, safari, scrolltop

We have a form in a sidebar on one of our pages which is fixed to a position as the visitor scrolls down the page.

I've just been made aware that on Safari, as soon as the visitor scrolls, the form flies way off the bottom of the screen rendering it useless and ineffective as no-one can submit it. It works as expected in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE (first for everything) so issue is only apparent in Safari.

That said however, I created a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/tcTKU/1/) of the scenario, and the same problem that occurs in Safari happens in the Jsfiddle (using Chrome). If you view the jsFiddle and scroll down, you'll see the issue that is occurring.

The jQuery in use is below:-

```
var $scrollingDiv = jQuery("#vfb_widget-2");
var elemTop = $scrollingDiv.offset().top - 80;

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
$scrollingDiv.stop();

if (jQuery(window).scrollTop()>elemTop) {
$scrollingDiv.animate({"marginTop": (jQuery(window).scrollTop()-elemTop) + "0px"}, "slow" );
} else {
$scrollingDiv.animate({"marginTop": "0px"}, "slow");
}
});
```

I'm aware of plenty of other questions on SO that are similar to this and many recommend using `html, body` instead of `window` but I've played around with a number of variations with no success so am thinking I haven't got this jQuery exactly right.

On the same website [where this form is in place](http://www.clubnetsem.com/strategy/organic-search-seo), the header also gets fixed to the top of the page when the visitor scrolls down hence the requirement for the top offset of 80.

If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's awful UX. Resize the [example where this form is in place](http://www.clubnetsem.com/strategy/organic-search-seo) so you have a shallow window... You can't scroll to the lower part of the form at all. Or view it at mobile size. Simply unusable.

Comment: @Moob Hmm - what browser are you using? That doesn't happen for me in Chrome. UX testing now.

Comment: Actually, I can see a ton of issues created by a plugin update it seems. Thanks, will get it all fixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your JSFiddle and i think it is fixed now: http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/tcTKU/2/

The problem was you were adding "0px" behind the margin-top, so practically you were adding this string 0px after the number that came out. So if the scrolltop-elemtop was 100, you would make it 1000px because of the 0px.

```
var $scrollingDiv = jQuery("#vfb_widget-2");
            var elemTop = $scrollingDiv.offset().top - 80;

            jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            $scrollingDiv.stop();

            if (jQuery(window).scrollTop()>elemTop) {
            $scrollingDiv.animate({"marginTop": (jQuery(window).scrollTop()-elemTop) + "px"}, "slow" );
            } else {
            $scrollingDiv.animate({"marginTop": "0px"}, "slow");
            }
            });
```

Comment: My oh my, the removal of the `0` - doh. That looks better, tested and confirmed works as expected on Safari now. Thanks very much :)